# Convert JSON envelop to List<MyNotification> using GSON lib android

Tags: android, gson, android-json

Only the first record is displayed while converting my JSON envelop to List using GSON library.  Why all records are not displayed ? The details about the json envelop, convert json to list and the item model is found below.

JSON envelop:

```
[{  
   "id_cur_profil":"2",
   "account_type":"job_provider",
   "notification":[  
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"124",
         "Name":"Buff Dudes",
         "city":"Namur",
         "activite":"Badminton",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-54ae5120d0a479.27096492.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"Wednesday",
               "from":"09:00:00",
               "to":"17:00:00"
            },
            {  
               "day":"Thursday",
               "from":"09:00:00",
               "to":"10:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"180",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Aikido",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"Monday",
               "from":"09:00:00",
               "to":"13:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"209",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Athletiek",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"Monday",
               "from":"09:00:00",
               "to":"13:00:00"
            },
            {  
               "day":"Tueday",
               "from":"13:00:00",
               "to":"21:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"242",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Tai Shi",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"243",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"244",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"245",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"246",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"247",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"248",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"{\"wednesday",
               "from":"09:00:00",
               "to":"17:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"249",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"253",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"254",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"255",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"%22%22",
               "from":"00:00:00",
               "to":"00:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"256",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"257",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"\"\"",
               "from":"00:00:00",
               "to":"00:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"258",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"259",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"monday",
               "from":"13:00:00",
               "to":"16:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"260",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  
            {  
               "day":"monday",
               "from":"13:00:00",
               "to":"16:00:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"261",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"267",
         "Name":"Annabelle Blaze",
         "city":"Waterloo",
         "activite":"Aerobic",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/jobber-5534a8c57fcf57.42394869.jpg",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "id_profil_request":"284",
         "Name":"Jobber Pro",
         "city":"Namur",
         "activite":"Boxe Thai",
         "logo":"https:\/\/app.com\/img\/profil_pic\/",
         "agenda":[  

         ]
      }
   ]
}]
```

Method to convert json to list.

```
public List<MyNotification> saveJson(String envelop){

        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyNotification>>() {}.getType();
        List<MyNotification> search_results  = new Gson().fromJson(envelop, listType);

        return search_results;
    }
```

The Json Model

```
public class MyNotification {

    public boolean no_record=false;

    public String error_message;
    public String id_cur_profil;
    public String account_type;
    public ArrayList<Notification> notification;

    public class Notification {

        public String id_profil_request;
        public String name;
        public String city;
        public String id_cur_profil;
        public String activite;
        public String logo;

        public ArrayList<Agenda> agenda;

    }

    public MyNotification(boolean b,String error_message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.no_record = b;
        this.error_message=error_message;
    }


}
```